# a strange behavior in Phaser with javascript

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

firstly

I am not beginner at game development at all - but beginner in web game development specially

I started with Phaser as it looks good and optimized for mobile games

anyway ..

I have a strange behavior with my game - I put a rectangle and trying to move it (when I debugged the X axis already changes correctly , but I can't see the rectangle move!!)

my codes

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight,Phaser.AUTO);
var colors = ["#FF0000" , "#00FF00" , "#0000FF" , "#FFFF00" , "#00FFFF" , "#FFFF00"];
var lst;
var hlprs = [];
var gameState = {
    preload: function () {
        this.game.stage.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
    },
    create: function () {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
        {
                hlprs[i] = new Phaser.Rectangle((i*200),0,100,20);
                hlprs[2*i + 1] = new Phaser.Rectangle((i*200),window.innerHeight - 20,100,20);

                game.debug.geom(hlprs[i] , colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 6))]);
                game.debug.geom(hlprs[2*i + 1] , colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 6))]);
        }
    },
    update: function ()
    {
        moving();// it calls moving function and X axis is changes but (the rectangle does not move !!!)
    }
};
function moving()
{
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
    {
        hlprs[i].offset(-1,0);
        hlprs[2*i + 1].offset(-1,0);
    }
}
game.state.add('GameState' , gameState);
game.state.start('GameState');
```

Answer (score 3):

Without testing it, I'd guess that what happens is the following: you create a bunch of shapes and do a single call to `game.debug.geom()` for each of the shapes. In the meantime the shapes do start moving, but since you never call `game.debug.geom()` again, you never see anything moving.

If you intend to use methods from `game.debug`, they should usually go inside the `render()` method of your state (which will be called once for every frame).

Note that the debug methods are to be used, well, for debugging. The proper way of displaying a shape is by making a sprite or an image (in which case you won't have to update anything manually since Phaser will handle it).

Answer (score 1):

Since the `update()` function calls `moving()` you might want to have your `game.debug` commands  within `moving`

```
function moving()
{
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
    {
       hlprs[i].offset(-1,0); 
       hlprs[2*i + 1].offset(-1,0);
       // update here
       game.debug.geom(hlprs[i] , colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 6))]);
       game.debug.geom(hlprs[2*i + 1] , colors[Math.floor((Math.random() * 6))]);            
    }
}
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/J5fUE/253/